# Fetch data from nested nodes in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building my first project in android using **`Firebase`**.

I have build a **`Firebase's database`** which is having main node as **post**, **media** as its child node, media node can contain multiple values for a particular post or can have one value inside it.

So i want to fetch media child node values with particular post node.

Could you please help me out.

Any help will deeply appreciated.

> Please check the screenshots below.

[image: Database image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(YOUR_FIREBASE_URL);
            String postNode ="KddShng........";
            ref.child("posts/"+postNode).child("media").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        Log.e("!_@@_Key : >",dataSnapshot.getKey()); // you will get key of Media node
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: i want to fetch the post node as well and inside that i want media node list.
would this do the same  ?

Comment: please Expand that node also.. put new image for it..so i can get idea

Answer (score 1):

First you need to read  [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) to know how to retrieve data from firebase.

and your data will be like this ...

```
final Firebase ref = new Firebase("URL/posts");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
//u can handle your variables name in GetData class
                GetData posts = userSnapshot.getValue(GetData.class);
```

In another way..

```
                DatabaseReference  databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");
                String user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
               databaseReference.child(user_id).child("media").getValue("user_id").getValue(etc);
```

You might save last line as `String` to reuse it anywhere.

**UPDATE:**

And to Fitch data You have to use Firebase [adapter](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/androidchat/FirebaseListAdapter.java), [example](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

Comment: i need post data and media child node data for particular post in single getset array. How to achieve that functionality?

Comment: Can you please send me github link for the same or any working example?

Comment: please check Update .

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts").child(UID).child("media");`

Where UID is the key of the particular post node.

PS: this returns something like a promise, for which you need to attach a listener for. (because this is real time)

Answer (score 0):

If just want to fetch the value once, you can do like this.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts").child("your_post_item_id").child("media").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

              for (DataSnapshot children : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  YourMediaModel mediaItem = children.getValue(YourMediaModel.class);
                  //add you mediaItem to list that you provided
              }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
```