# How to query from a parameter in child nodes in firebase database for android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get data according to the values in the child nodes. I need to get the semesters but by querying the value of BCT that is in the subjects child.
[image]

How can we achieve this in Android?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408913/fetch-data-from-nested-nodes-in-firebase

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("semester").child("0").child("subjects").child("0");

mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        boolean guestType = dataSnapshot.child("BCT").getValue(Boolean.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
});
```